# ReactJS: Sum quantity for unique items

Tags: reactjs

I have the following object/array:

```
[
    {
        "id": null,
        "value": "Apples",
        "label": "Apples",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Weight": "0.075",
        "inputQuantity": "2",
        "Category": "BREAKFAST",
        "ItemCopy": 2,
        "PM": "123"
    },
    {
        "Quantity": 1,
        "value": "Apples",
        "Weight": "0.075",
        "id": null,
        "label": "Apples",
        "inputQuantity": "3",
        "Category": "BREAKFAST",
        "ItemCopy": 2,
        "PM": "123"
    },
    {
        "value": "Asparagus",
        "id": "TnwiO97ZHCsz4vl9A9OR",
        "label": "Asparagus",
        "Weight": "0.185",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "inputQuantity": "3",
        "Category": "BREAKFAST",
        "ItemCopy": 1,
        "PM": "123"
    }
]
```

I then use the following code to get them down to unique values:

```
  function getUniqueDataCount(objArr, propName) {
    const mi = [...objArr]
    var data = [];
    objArr.forEach(function (d, index) {
      if (d[propName]) {
        data.push(d[propName]);
      }
    });
    var uniqueList = [...new Set(data)];
    var dataSet = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      dataSet[uniqueList[i]] = data.filter(x => x == uniqueList[i]).length;
      mi[i].ItemCopy = data.filter(x => x == data[i]).length
    }
    return mi;
  }

 useMemo(() => {
    mydata = getUniqueDataCount(daataa, 'label');
  }, [daataa])

  useMemo(() => {
    newCheck = Object.values(mydata?.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, { [cur?.label]: cur }), {}))
  }, [mydata])
```

The newCheck object/array then becomes:

```
[
    {
        "Quantity": 1,
        "value": "Apples",
        "Weight": "0.075",
        "id": null,
        "label": "Apples",
        "inputQuantity": "2",
        "Category": "BREAKFAST",
        "ItemCopy": 2
    },
    {
        "value": "Asparagus",
        "id": "TnwiO97ZHCsz4vl9A9OR",
        "label": "Asparagus",
        "Weight": "0.185",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "inputQuantity": "2",
        "Category": "BREAKFAST",
        "ItemCopy": 1
    }
]
```

Which is more or less what I want, but within this newCheck object/array it is not calculating the inputQuantity correctly - it should be 5 for Apples, and 3 for Asparagus.

How do I modify this, so for every unique ingredient it gets the inputQuantity of every occurrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `Array.reduce` method for efficient grouping

```
function getUniqueDataCount(objArr, propName) {
  return objArr.reduce((c,data)=>{
       c[data[propName]] ??= {...data, inputQuantity:0};
       c[data[propName]].inputQuantity += Number(data.inputQuantity);
       return c;
  },{});
}

useMemo(() => {
    newCheck = Object.values(getUniqueDataCount(daataa, 'label'));
    console.log(newCheck)
}, [daataa])
```

Check out this:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": null,
        "value": "Apples",
        "label": "Apples",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Weight": "0.075",
        "inputQuantity": "2",
        "Category": "BREAKFAST",
        "ItemCopy": 2,
        "PM": "123"
    },
    {
        "Quantity": 1,
        "value": "Apples",
        "Weight": "0.075",
        "id": null,
        "label": "Apples",
        "inputQuantity": "3",
        "Category": "BREAKFAST",
        "ItemCopy": 2,
        "PM": "123"
    },
    {
        "value": "Asparagus",
        "id": "TnwiO97ZHCsz4vl9A9OR",
        "label": "Asparagus",
        "Weight": "0.185",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "inputQuantity": "3",
        "Category": "BREAKFAST",
        "ItemCopy": 1,
        "PM": "123"
    }
]

const res = data.reduce((c,data)=>{
  c[data["label"]] ??= {...data, inputQuantity:0};
  c[data["label"]].inputQuantity += Number(data.inputQuantity);
  return c;
},{});

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Understand. But this is still not tallying the inputQuantities for each unique item - ie. Apples should be 5

Comment: Yeah it return `inputQuantity` 5 for apple, run the code snippet to check

Comment: Cool, thanks - how do I incorporate this into my existing function? It returns an error if I simply replace it with your provided.

Comment: what error? post it

Comment: All good - just had to change a variable on my end! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be:

```js
const getUniqueDataCount = (data, prop) => {
  const result = {}
  data.forEach(entry => {
    if (!result[entry[prop]]) {
      result[entry[prop]] = {...entry, "inputQuantity": +entry["inputQuantity"]}
    } else {
      result[entry[prop]]["inputQuantity"] += +entry["inputQuantity"]
    }
  })
  return Object.values(result)
}
```

The input Array will be looped only once and the quantity will be converted into a number, to be able to sum the values of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue , but i didnt find any thing fruitfull